# Custom path to my iOS xcworkspace/xcproj file

Tags: react-native

How can I specify where my native iOS project is? Because my iOS project is in subfolder of `ios` folder. For example `ios/myProject`.

Answer (score 0):

If you check code for `local-cli` code which responsible for command `react-native run-ios`, you can see that it runs a function called [`findXcodeProject`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/dbc9364b2142c4ad908d7d30a15361f113bb429b/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js#L60) which takes a path argument. This path argument is hard coded in the project so I don't thing there is an option to change the default behavior unless you change the source code. You can fork and submit a PR if you think this is a required behavior for the project.